# Adjoint of linear operator is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show that in a unitary space, the adjoint $A^{*}$ of a linear operator $A$ is itself linear. I'm using the definition which defines the adjoint through the inner product.

$$ (A^*\psi,\phi) \equiv (\psi, A\phi) .$$

If I substitute $$\psi = a\psi_1 + b\psi_2$$ and use the (bi)linearity of the inner product, I get that for arbitrary $\phi$

$$(A^* (a\psi_1 + b\psi_2),\phi) = a(A^*\psi_1,\phi) + b(A^*\psi_2,\phi)$$

This sort of looks like linearity, but I would like to "cancel" the "$,\phi)$", this looks like the right approach. But I think I lack the necessary tools at this point. I don't think I used the fact that $A$ is linear at all, but the adjoint is only defined for linear operators, right? What should I do next?

Comment: Note that the equality holds _for all $\phi$_, then use a density argument to conclude.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've just started reading about this, it's for a quantum mechanics course.

Comment: Use the fact that if a vector $u$ is orthogonal to everybody, then it is equal to $0$.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. I should just subtract the RHS from both sides and use linearity of the inner product again, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\langle A^* (\lambda_1 \psi_1 + \lambda_2 \psi_2) - (\lambda_1 A^* \psi_1 + \lambda_2 A^* \psi_2), \phi \rangle = 0$ for all $\phi$.

Choose $\phi = A^* (\lambda_1 \psi_1 + \lambda_2 \psi_2) - (\lambda_1 A^* \psi_1 + \lambda_2 A^* \psi_2)$ to conclude that
$A^* (\lambda_1 \psi_1 + \lambda_2 \psi_2) - (\lambda_1 A^* \psi_1 + \lambda_2 A^* \psi_2) = 0$.